# how to reset react hooks state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a little bit new to react, I read [this doc about hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and I have a popover with Show More option. The show more function need to show an extra text when it clicked and hide after popover is gone.

the popover function is:

```
export default function Popover(props) {

  const [viewDetails, setViewDetails] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
          <h5>{props.title}</h5>

          {viewDetails ?
            'yes, more details here ...' : 'no'}

          <span onClick={() => {setViewDetails(!viewDetails); console.log(viewDetails)}}>Show more</span>

    </div>
  );
}
```

and I need a simple local variable which will have 'the state' only when the popover is active.

Why I can't do something like:

```
export default function Popover(props) {

      let viewDetails = false;

      return (
        <div>
              <h5>{props.title}</h5>

              {viewDetails ?
                'yes, more details here ...' : 'no'}

              <span onClick={() => {viewDetails = !viewDetails; console.log(viewDetails)}}>Show more</span>

        </div>
      );
    }
```

? I see that the value is **always** `false` when the popover is shown and I can set it to true on click but the `{viewDetails ? 'yes, more details here ...' : 'no'}` doesn't change

Comment: You are actually showing the purpose of hooks: keeping a state value between function calls. In your second example, each time `Popover` is rendered, `viewDetails` is created and set to false, therefore you don't see any UI changes. Why don't you want to use `useState` ?

Comment: It's not very clear what the problem is. The first code snippet already works as you describe (extra text is shown when `viewDetails` is true.)

Comment: @GaëlS I don't want to show more details if the button is not clicked and I think this is the easiest way ...I want to have the variable only when the popover is active

Comment: @JJJ the problem is that in the first example I don't want to show more details if the mouse is again over popover trigger and in the second example the shortif is not working

Comment: Still unclear what that means. Do you mean that you only want to show the message once, and when the user clicks on the button the message is removed and never shown again (regardless of how many times the user clicks the button again)? Then you'd just add a separate state hook.

Comment: the question is: why in the second example the ```{viewDetails ? 'yes, more details here ...' : 'no'}``` is not working

Comment: ...because you have `viewDetails = false` at the start of the function? Do you expect it to somehow magically know that it should execute that line only when the function is called the first time?

Comment: @JJJ no, only when I clicked on the show more btn span -> ```onClick={() => {viewDetails = !viewDetails.....```

Comment: Ok, you should probably go back to reading the basics of how React works. If you don't use state, React doesn't know that it should re-render the component when you click on the span, and even if it did, it re-renders by *calling the function again* in which case you would just immediately reset the variable value.

Comment: @JJJ ok, then the conclusion is: I can't update a variable without being part of a state?

Comment: You can't update a *local* variable because calling the function would always reset it, and it wouldn't trigger a re-render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable which **is not** a state variable can not cause a re-render.

You can solve this via [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Move how you set the view to the parent component.

```
function Details(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h5>{props.title}</h5>
      <span>{props.details}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

function Popover(props) {
  const [view, setView] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      { view && <Details details={props.details} /> }
      <span onClick={() => setView(!view)}>
        Show { view ? 'less': 'more' }
      </span>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: yes... but the state will persist ... I need a simple variable every time the ```Popover``` function is render

Comment: A variable which is **not** a state variable **can not** cause a re-render.